How to proxy Firebase Auth calls to bypass regional restrictions (identitytoolkit.googleapis.com domain)?
I’m using the firebase/auth NPM package for user authentication with Google Login and Email/Password. It works great in most places, but some users in China and Iran can’t use my app because the requests to identitytoolkit.googleapis.com are blocked.
It seems like some VPNs also block these calls, which makes things even harder.
Is there any way to make firebase/auth send these requests through a proxy, like one under my own domain?
If that’s not possible, what would be a good workaround to let these users log in?
Thanks for your help!
I'm already using the "authDomain" config and it works fine, but it doesn't solve the issue where identitytoolkit.googleapis.com requests are blocked.

You can send Firebase (or any request) through any network interface you configure (Networking 101). The issue is configuring the user's network and using a VPN that supports the desired network traffic. I don't know anything about regional network issues in Iran, but for China, I do not recommend you support circumventing the Chinese government controls. China forbids (censors) almost anything Google related. You have technical, legal, and political issues to consider.


The simplest way would be to change the app code to make network calls to use a proxy. If it is not possible - 2. Find a VPN provider that does not block requests to these URLs. If it is not possible -
You can force the app traffic to be routed through the proxy using external mechanisms. You can find such solutions using keywords such as proxyfiacation, proxify, etc.


As an example:
Find the proxy that does not block requests to needed target resources and work in your client's country.
Set Up https://www.proxifier.com/ or tun2socs or https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray and use rules to route only problematoc domain via proxy.
